# FCM Node JS Server,

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi i working with Node JS and Firebase SDK,

Im trying to send FCM notificacion as documentation says: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages?hl=es-419,

My code:

```
function testMessage(){
    let token="f8mNlJq4VOY:APA91bF5_8ldOZEm34ajCfNx7hZ9_LhjUBQFDwZbtSnCNEzb1bEtMsXKlM8upyicvmnJ92xELZzDSxTMaeZrCrrau"
    let message={
         notification: {
    title: "Account Deposit",
    body: "A deposit to your savings account has just cleared."
  },
         data: {
    score: '850',
    time: '2:45'
  },
  token:token
    };
    admin.messaging().send(message)
  .then((response) => {
    // Response is a message ID string.
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });
}
```

But when i execute, this show this error:

> Error sending message: { Error: Request contains an invalid argument.
>       at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Monitora\Demos\BackEnd\APIMonitora\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:39:28)
>       at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Monitora\Demos\BackEnd\APIMonitora\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:85:28)
>       at new FirebaseMessagingError (C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Monitora\Demos\BackEnd\APIMonitora\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:241:16)
>       at Function.FirebaseMessagingError.fromServerError (C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Monitora\Demos\BackEnd\APIMonitora\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:271:16)
>       at C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Monitora\Demos\BackEnd\APIMonitora\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\messaging\messaging-api-request.js:149:50
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)   errorInfo:    { code: 'messaging/invalid-argument',
>        message: 'Request contains an invalid argument.' },   codePrefix: 'messaging' }

The SDK its loading, and dependences are workin. 
Can you help me to fix it?

Comment: Its my error, 
The limit of String on my database dont store all content of field, and results in that error:

Answer (score 0):

Sorry its my error, 
The limit of String on my database dont store all ID fixing this problem, code looks:

```
function testMessage(){
    let registrationToken ='f8mNlJq4VOY:APA91bF5_8ldOZEm34ajCfNx7hZ9_LhjUBQFDwZbtSnCNEzb1bEtMsXKlM8upyicvmnJ92xELZzDSxTMaeZrCrrau-S0mmNdMC18Mp3rwLnUGy-cXM8caoiCJQjEpDDy6FChDwtmO3n2';
    let message={       
    notification: {
    title: "Portugal vs. Denmark",
    body: "5 to 1"
     },
        data: {
    score: '850',
    time: '2:45'
        },
  token: registrationToken

};
admin.messaging().send(message)
  .then((response) => {
    // Response is a message ID string.
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });
}
```